# How can I fix a RangeError in a List of Objects in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to make a list of objects in my app. I have some data collected from Firestore and other it's mock data at least for now. I've created a method and with a For loop trying to populate a List with the generated Objects.
I'm constantly getting the error "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1".

What I've tried? 
-First I thought it may be a problem with Firestore Data, maybe something wasn't ready at the time of the assignment, so I create fake variables to fill the object. Didn't worked.
-I thought it could have something to do with the For loop, I commented out and didn't solved anything.
-Read somewhere the [index] variable could be the problem so  I put a number in the List[value], and the error changed from "..is empty: 1" to "..is empty: X" X=number I put in there.

```
class comida{
Comida(this.name, this.descripcion,this.likes)

String name, descripcion;
int likes;}

---------------------------------------------------------------

creacionMenu(Map<dynamic,dynamic>name, 
Map<dynamic,dynamic>descripcion, 
Map<dynamic,dynamic>likes){

List<Comida> menu;
for (var i = 1; i < likes.length; i++) {
menu[i]=Comida(name['$i'], descripcion['$i'], likes['$i']);
}
return menu;
}
```

Thats a very simplified version of my code. I know my error must be in the way I've tried to declare the List or how assign value. But can't find a way around it.
Any help would be very apreciatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you write a value in `menu` starting at index 1 but `List` must start at 0.

Prefer the use of `menu.add()` or use a `Map<int, Comida>` for `menu`.